# How to Override the style of Layout component in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

- I am using Next.js with Material-UI as the framework.
- I have Layout component that wraps the contents with Material-UI `<Container>`.
- I would like to override the style of Layout that limits the width of background, so that the background would extend to the full screen.

**components/Layout.js**

```js
import { Container } from '@material-ui/core';

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return <Container>{children}</Container>;
}
```

**pages/_app.js**

```js
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

...
<Layout>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
</Layout>
...
```

**pages/index.js**

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
      Home Page
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image: example]

Using Layout component comes in handy in most cases but sometimes I do want to override the certain styles of Layout from the child component.

In this case, how do I override the style of Layout component that puts the limit on maxWidth?

I tried to add `{width: '100vw'}` inside the style of pages/index.js, but did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

[Link to the SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-clarke-yij5p)

Comment: it looks like the `Layout` component is not accepting any props except children. Take all the props and pass them to `Container` element. `({ children, ...restProps })` and then spread the `...restProps` inside the `Container` like this, `<Container {...restProps}>`

Answer (score 0):

Using `React Context` is how I've solved this issue.

**context/ContainerContext.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

const ContainerContext = React.createContext();

export default ContainerContext;
```

**components/Layout.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import ContainerContext from '../context/ContainerContext';

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const [hasContainer, setHasContainer] = useState(true);

  const Wrapper = hasContainer ? Container : React.Fragment;

  return (
    <ContainerContext.Provider value={{ hasContainer, setHasContainer }}>
      <Wrapper>{children}</Wrapper>
    </ContainerContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**pages/index.js**

```js
import { useContext, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import ContainerContext from '../context/ContainerContext';

export default function App() {
  const { setHasContainer } = useContext(ContainerContext);

  // Where the magic happens!
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setHasContainer(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
      Home Page
    </div>
  );
}
```